# Single Page App: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, css

I have simple code which is a single page application. I have few html headers with each assigned to different class names. I'm trying to show/hide them based on signal received by the websocket. Also I have bind onclick event to some of these headers. But once I click the header it throws an error that the function is not defined. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MultiTask Performance Testing</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .loading {
            display: none;
        }
        .overview {
            display: none;
        }
        .charge {
            display: none;
        }
        .discharge {
            display: none;
        }
        .active {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- LOADING SCREEN -->
    <h1 class="loading active">Loading....</h1>

    <!-- OVERVIEW SCREEN -->
    <br />
    <a id="screen1-charge" class="overview" onclick="myFunction()" href="#">enter loading mode</a>
    <br />
    <a id="screen1-discharge" class="overview" onclick="dischargeFunction()" href="#">enter discharge mode</a>

    <!-- CHARGE SCREEN -->
    <h1 class="charge">CHARGE</h1>

    <!-- DISCHARGE SCREEN -->
    <h1 class="discharge">DISCHARGE</h1>

</body>

<script src="vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="socketHandler.js"></script>
<script>
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            console.log("*** READY ***");
            var socketController = new ReconnectingWebSocket("ws://localhost:1337");

            function myFunction() {

                console.log("###############INSIDE myFunction###########");
                //socketController.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(["sig-request-enter-charge"]));
            }

            function dischargeFunction()
            {
                socketController.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(["sig-request-enter-discharge"]));
            }

        }
    };
</script>

</html>
```

**Part of SocketHandler.js file**

```
function ReconnectingWebSocket(url, protocols) {
...
this.onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = event.data;

        try{
            // If the string is UTF-8, this will work and not throw an error.
            data= decodeURIComponent(escape(data));
        }catch(e){  }

        var msg = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log("*** *** *** Message received :" + msg[0]);

        if (msg[0] == "error") {
            console.error(msg[1]);
        }
        else if(msg[0] == "sig-app-state-changed")
        {
            console.log("*****inside else if statement");
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('overview');
            for (var i in elements) {
                if (elements.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    elements[i].className = 'overview active';

                }
            }

            var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('loading active');
            for(var i in elementy){
                if(elementy.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    elementy[i].className = 'loading';
                }
            }
        }
        else if(msg[0] == "sig-reply-enter-charge"){
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('overview');
            for (var i in elements) {
                if (elements.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    elements[i].className = 'overview active';

                }
            }
            var elementy = document.getElementsByClassName('charge');
            for(var i in elementy){
                if(elementy.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    elementy[i].className = 'charge active';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //SignalsController.parseMessage(msg);
            console.log("inside else condition");
            //console.log(msg[1])
            console.log("--received--->", msg);
        }
...
}
```

**How it looks after receiving signal "sig-app-state-changed"**
[image]

Comment: you have to place the myFunction outside document.onreadystatechange

Comment: @NishadKAhamed — It is best to avoid global variables where possible.

Comment: I think this a simple scenario and making the variables and function global will solve the issue. I didn't see lot of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations create a variable in **the current scope**.

You have declared `function myFunction() {` inside the anonymous function you assign to `document.onreadystatechange` so it can only be accessed from inside that function.

You are trying to call it from outside that function, so it doesn't exist.

---

Bind your event handlers using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (and do it from inside the right scope) instead of using `onclick` attributes.

Comment: can you please give me an example code? I'm new to Js

Comment: The MDN documentation I linked to includes several examples.

Comment: Thanks, solved it by making the socketController a global variable and placing myFunction() outside the document.onreadystatechange()